# textsl in Beamer

Tags: beamer, italic, slanted

I notice that the `\textit` and `\textsl` behave much alike in Beamer. The following MWE produces the image:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\textsl{Welcome to my world!}

\textit{Welcome to my world!}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image].

How can these two can be made different, as they are in Article class:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\textsl{Welcome to my world!}

\textit{Welcome to my world!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: beamer uses a sans font by default. It is asking a lot of a font designer to come up with  a sans serif "italic" font that isn't just slanted.

Comment: Slanted sans serif is a relatively new invention (and I don't like it at all). Italic sans serif doesn't really make sense, as italics should, in some sense, emulate handwriting.

Comment: @egreg if you're lucky someone will buy you this for your birthday http://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/comic-sans/italic

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Too bad it isn't possible to downvote comments ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If choosing another `fonttheme` you will see, that beamer makes a difference between `textsl` and `textit`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{}
        \textsl{Welcome to my world!}

        \textit{Welcome to my world!}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or if you want to use sans serif font you can change the font locally (inside the frame) using `\begin{frame}\rmfamily`.

Comment: I accepted, although I liked the default `beamer` font.